When starting XRebel, an exception is thrown. I am using version 3.2.6 of spring-boot and version 10.1.24 of tomcat-embed-core
XRebel: ERROR Class 'org.apache.catalina.connector.Response' could not be processed by com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.reqint.http.XrHttpServletResponseCBP@null: com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: setStatus(..) is not found in org.apache.catalina.connector.Response
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getDeclaredMethod(XRebel:1363)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.reqint.http.XrHttpServletResponseCBP.a(XRebel:88)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.reqint.http.XrHttpServletResponseCBP.process(XRebel:71)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.cbp.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(XRebel:48)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.bootstrap.q.a(XRebel:101)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.bootstrap.q.a(XRebel:29)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.bootstrap.q$1.a(XRebel:77)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.bootstrap.q$1.a(XRebel:66)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.nq$2.run(XRebel:35)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.security.sdk.SecurityController.doWithoutSecurityManager(XRebel:32)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.nu.a(XRebel:18)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.nq.a(XRebel:32)
at com.zeroturnaround.xrebel.bootstrap.q.transform(XRebel:66)
at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl._jrDoTransform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl._jrTransform(InstrumentationImpl.java:42001)
at java.base/com.zeroturnaround.jrebelbase.reorder.b.transform(SourceFile:180)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:43001)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader._jr$defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:43016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.createResponse(Connector.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:308)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
I have tried other versions of JRebel, but encountered issues. The current version I am using is 2024.3.0.
